# Migrating code from rendering SVG to Canvas/WebGL - what are my options?

Tags: svg, webgl

I'm looking at some older code which is rendering some images, animations, etc... for a website by generating a web page containing significant SVG elements. The result is a fairly complicated, interactive, interface. I've been tasked with migrating the application to instead generate WebGL calls.

This is a non-trivial task, considering all of the niceties that come with SVG, which are not directly available if going straight to a WebGL implementation. I've been debating whether I should pitch migrating to using something like Three.js instead, but don't know enough about the available options to make a good decision.

What are some reasonable options I should consider when trying to build my battle plan here?

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether there's any SVG like library that runs on top of WebGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look at http://code.google.com/p/canvg/ as an option.

I assume it is using getContext("2d") not getContext("experimental-webgl") or getContext("webgl").

WebGL provides a 3d interface and I am not sure if there is any advantage to using it for 2d graphics, since you don't have any 3d transforms for the GPU to work on. If they are interested in Canvas not specifically webgl ... Canvg would bring over some of the niceties of SVG which would be the source content.

If the issue is lack of support for SVG in browsers http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/ goes a long way to solving that problem.